# Add to Cart from the Quote page not working

Tags: product, cart, quote

I put a link at the bottom of the quote page to up-sell a service plan on tires within the cart.

`<a href="/checkout/cart/add?product=<?php echo $id?>&qty=4">Add</a>`

The problem is that the cart doesn't display the added product when the cart page refreshes.

I debugged the CartController and the product is added and saved correctly. But when I debug the cart template the newly added item is not displayed.

Comment: I'm using Magento 1.7x.  I found another post about the URLs not working in 1.8.

Comment: So...looks like the problem is with the product. I hard coded another product ID and it was added to the product ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got so lost in the code I forgot to check the obvious - the product was disabled!

DAMN...

Open to public flogging...

Thanks to all those to spent time reading this...

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're not using the catalog helper:

\Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare::getAddToCartUrl

```
<?php echo $helper->getAddToCartUrl($product) ?>
```